# Round trip time string to long in Java?

Tags: java, datetime

I have a timedate string in a round-trip data pattern like this: `2012-07-05T11:30:44.1533815Z`. This comes from some .NET service.

How do I convert it to a `long` in Java?

I've tried `SimpleDateTimeFormat` seems I can't figure out the correct format specifiers..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public long getTime(String time) throws ParseException {
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'");
  Date date = df.parse(time);

  return date.getTime();
}
```

cheers

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse it to a Date using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

From a date, you can get, using getTime(), the unix epoch in milliseconds, which is a long.

This would start like this :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
long myTime = format.parse("2012-07-05T11:30:44.1533815Z").getTime();
```

But you have to check what's the meaning of the last chars of your date ? Is that a timezone definition ? If you don't determine it and simply escape it, you'll risk to interpret the date with a bad time zone.

Comment: the last character means the time is measured in UTC, see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'");
    long time = dateFormat.parse("2012-07-05T11:30:44.1533815Z").getTime();
} catch (ParseException e) {
              .....
}
```

Comment: the last seven m's are incorrect. Small m is for minute in hour.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a datetime in the iso format, you can easily parse it using the excellent Joda datetime library as this:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime("2012-07-05T11:30:44.1533815Z");
long dtl = dt.getMillis();
```

See [Joda Userguide](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html) under the "Input and Output" chapter and http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html. It will take care of parsing the ISO8601 format in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Please note this, If i am giving dateTime UTC `"2017-07-13T05:43:24.6966215Z"` it gives me back in IST `Thu Jul 13 07:39:30 IST 2017` instead of `Thu Jul 13 11:13:25 IST 2017`

```
String rawDate = "2017-07-13T05:43:24.6966215Z";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(rawDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

So after gone through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44000968/4436435) i came to know this given string is not Date format rather than ISO Instant format.

> Milliseconds (SSS) can only be three digits. On more than that, the date rolls over - e.g. 10:38:14.1000 becomes 10:38:15.000.

To convert Instant to Date Object

```
String rawDate = "2017-07-13T05:43:24.6966215Z";
DateTimeFormatter instantFormater = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
Instant instant = Instant.from(instantFormater.parse(rawDate));
System.out.println(Date.from(instant));
```

It gives expected `Thu Jul 13 11:13:24 IST 2017`
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19726814/4436435)