# Migrate from Hibernate 4.3.6 to Hibernate 5

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-5.x

I have old project where I use Date from Java API, and I want change this to new Java 8 Date API to `LocalDateTime`. I read that Hibernate version before 5 does not support the new Java 8 Date API, and I decided to migrate from Hibernate 4.3.6 to 5. In old project version everything works fine, but when I change the  Hibernate version, I get error when I try start my application:

```
    wrz 21, 2015 7:14:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/lib/amd64;D:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;D:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;D:\Program Files\eclipse;;.
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:23 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:iBank' did not find a matching property.
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:23 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:webClient' did not find a matching property.
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8181"]
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1096 ms
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:25 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [161] milliseconds.
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Sep 21 19:14:31 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: iBankPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: iBankPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:805)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table transfers add constraint FK1vp11ydp2tn6fufhmfcr2is8x foreign key (fromAccId) references usersAccounts]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applyForeignKeys(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1036)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1845)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1810)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56)
    ... 36 more
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: iBankPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: iBankPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:805)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table transfers add constraint FK1vp11ydp2tn6fufhmfcr2is8x foreign key (fromAccId) references usersAccounts]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applyForeignKeys(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1036)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1845)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1810)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56)
    ... 36 more

wrz 21, 2015 7:14:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ibank] startup failed due to previous errors
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:37 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/ibank] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:37 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/ibank] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap] (value [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap@3de81e58]) and a value of type [java.util.Hashtable] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8181"]
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
wrz 21, 2015 7:14:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 13368 ms
```

I only change my pom file:

```
    <properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And mayby my root-context file can be useful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd">
    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="pl.piotr.ibank" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
        <property name="username" value="HR" />
        <property name="password" value="asdfghj" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="iBankPU" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.piotr.ibank.model" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="pl.piotr.ibank.security.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

</beans>
```

UserAccount Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usersAccounts")
public class UserAccount implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "accountNr")
    private String accountNr;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "balance")
    private float balance;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "createDate")
    private LocalDateTime createDate;
    @Column(name = "expiredDate")
    private LocalDateTime expiredDate;
    @Column(name = "lastOperation")
    private LocalDateTime lastOperation;
    @Column(name = "transfersCount")
    private int transfersCount;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "investmentId")
    private InvestmentType investmentType;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "personalAccountId")
    private PersonalAccountType personalAccountType;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "savingAccountId")
    private SavingAccountType savingAccountType;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userAccountFrom", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Transfer> transferFromSet;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userAccountTo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Transfer> transferToSet;

    ...

}
```

Transfer Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transfers")
public class Transfer implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@NotNull
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;
@NotNull
@Column(name = "transferDate")
private LocalDateTime transferDate;
@NotNull
@Column(name = "amount")
private float amount;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fromAccId")
private UserAccount userAccountFrom;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "toAccId")
private UserAccount userAccountTo;

....
}
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table` this is actually your problem. Can you clear the database and restart the project and try? I guess your query is wrong.

Comment: @Lucky I clear DB and restart project, and I still get this error. I think the problem is EntityManagerFactory, but i don't now how to solve it.

Comment: This is because you are using `hbm2ddl` and defining a foreign key or something twice ... can you post your entity mapping ?

Comment: @Pras I added entity in post. But everything works ok when i use Hibernate 4.3.6. This error I get when I change the Hibernate to version 5 and field from Date to LocalDateTime.

Comment: Also post the class that represents the `transfers` and `userAccounts` tables.

Comment: this : `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userAccountFrom", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Transfer> transferFromSet;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userAccountTo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Transfer> transferToSet;~` ... on the other side, `transfer`entity : you have two `ManyToOne` referencing same foreign key

Comment: @Pras I don't see anything wrong in this realtion. Can you expand your answer? I remind, this work in Hibernate 4.3.6.

Comment: thing is : code has been changed from hibernate 4 to hibernate 5 concerning that hbm2ddl ... what value do you have for that property in your configuration file ? did you change anything in there ? something like from `update` to `create-drop`?

Comment: Bit of a shot in the dark, but try specifying an `@ForeignKey` http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html for the two transfer sets.

Comment: Both sides of a bi-directional association cannot be specified mappedBy.  One side has to be non-mappedBy.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750026/java-8-localdatetime-and-hibernate-4), I also migrate to from Hibernate 4 to Hibernate 5 to take advantage of the new Java `LocalDateTime` API, then I started having the same issue as you: `ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table`.

I solved the issue by adding the property:`<prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42237105/2737790).

Then I started having another issue, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968527/hibernate-sequence-doesnt-exist), where Hibernate was not finding the sequence, which in my case was solved by replacing all `GenerationType.AUTO` annotations by `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`.

**UPDATE:** Later, all my sequences values were getting multiplied by 50 like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989290/hibernate-sequence-gets-multiplied-by-50-for-id-generation), so I had to add this `allocationSize = 1` in my domain classes.