JPA entity ID field with a SQL Server 2022 Sequence
I am trying to connect my Spring Boot service to a SQL Server 2022 database, but I am having issues with a sequence:
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "some_seq", schema = "sch_some", sequenceName = "some_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "some_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "decimal")
    private Long id;
    ...
}

This is the error that I am getting when I am trying to store something in the table:

{"date":"2024-07-07T20:50:08,250Z","env":"test","app":"some-service","version":"1.32.0","host":"_","level":"ERROR","logger":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]","msg":"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work] with root cause","thread":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","context":[],"eventId":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException","stack":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'some_db.sch_some.some_seq'.\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1624)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:594)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2979)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:446)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\n\tat

Here is how I created the sequence
create sequence SCH_SOME.SOME_SEQ start with 1 increment by 1;

Since I have another table in this schema that has no problems with insertions, I am thinking that this may be be access issue. I also tried to run a grant select statement, as I would in Oracle, but I ended up getting this

SQL Error [4606] [S0001]: Granted or revoked privilege SELECT is not compatible with object.

So in SQL Server, is there another set of permissions that I need to run the grant for? I've also tried UPDATE and ALTER, but that didn't make a difference. If anyone could shed some light on this issues, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
Update - I did some debugging, and found that this is what Hibernate is generating:
Hibernate: 
    select
        next_val as id_val 
    from
        some_db.sch_some.some_seq with (updlock,
        rowlock)

I don't think this is the correct syntax for SQL Server.

This question been asked many times before e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037803/sql-server-2016-invalid-object-name-hibernate-sequence and one thing you need to check is that you have the latest drivers and are using the correct SqlServer dialect.

What versions of Spring, Hibernate and JPA are you using? The syntax it's using is totally incorrect for SQL Server, it should be closer to select next value for SCH_SOME.SOME_SEQ as [id_val];. Ref: db<>fiddle

Yes that is correct, I ended up changing the hibernate dialect from org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect to org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect and it fixed the issue.
