# Hibernate-sequence doesn't exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I tried to upgrade hibernate from 4 to 5 in my project with spring `4.2` version. After this upgrade, I found the following error in my stack trace when I called a method for updating.

```
10:53:32,185 ERROR TableStructure:149 - could not read a hi value
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
```

I changed the auto incremented Id with annotation

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

still the error remains.

Comment: try setting in config file `<prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815625/migration-from-hibernate-4-to-5

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You need to set for Hibernate5.x `<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property>`.. see and [link](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc#changed-setting-defaults).

For older version of hibernate 4.x:
`<prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>`

Comment: where does this get added?

Comment: add this in hibernate properties.

Comment: JavaDocs of interest - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html#USE_NEW_ID_GENERATOR_MAPPINGS

Comment: Your answer might be the solution to the question, but it does not explain why it resolves the problem. Please keep in mind, that links tend to die.

Comment: I know it is a bit late for questions, but what is the difference between jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: false and jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings: false? Because with your answers everything works, but with use-new-id-generator-mappings: false don't. I am confused because there are a lot of people on Internet which make they applications work with both. I am using Hibernate 5 with Spring v1.5.6.RELEASE.

Comment: after I add <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property> in hibernate.cfg.xml, still show this error, still get sequence from hibernate_sequence

Answer (score 133):

You can also put :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

And let the DateBase manage the incrementation of the primary key:

```
AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: This might be good in some cases, but has an obvious drawback: every `INSERT` is gonna cause one additional round trip to the Database to fetch the ID. So when this drawback is acceptable, fine.

Comment: @G.Demecki would you be able to discuss the pros and cons of using hibernates identity generator in contrast to this round trip method? Would be really useful!

Answer (score 57):

Working with **Spring Boot**

#### Solution

Put the string below in .application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
```

#### Explanation

On Hibernate 4.X this attribute defaults to `true`.

Answer (score 32):

This is the reason behind this error:

It will look for how the database that you are using generates ids. For MySql or HSQSL, there are increment fields that automatically increment. In Postgres or Oracle, they use sequence tables. Since you didn't specify a sequence table name, it will look for a sequence table named hibernate_sequence and use it for default. So you probably don't have such a sequence table in your database and now you get that error.

Comment: should be marked as an answer as this explains things simply - ofcourse an addition of "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false" should be mentioned but thanks.

Answer (score 18):

FYI

If you are using hbm files to define the O/R mapping.

Notice that:

In Hibernate 5, **the param name for the sequence name has been changed**.

The following setting worked fine in **Hibernate 4**:

```
<generator class="sequence">
    <param name="sequence">xxxxxx_seq</param>
</generator>
```

But in **Hibernate 5**, the same mapping setting file will cause a "hibernate_sequence doesn't exist" error.

To fix this error, the param name **must change** to:

```
<generator class="sequence">
    <param name="sequence_name">xxxxxx_seq</param>
</generator>
```

This problem wasted me 2, 3 hours.

And somehow, it looks like there are **no document** about it.

I have to read the source code of org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator to figure it out

Comment: That right there solved it for me after upgrading from Hibernate 3 to 5.

Answer (score 16):

I was getting the same error "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mylocaldb.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist".

Using spring mvc 4.3.7 and hibernate version 5.2.9, application is made using spring java based configuration. Now I have to add the `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` property mentioned by @Eva Mariam in my code like this:

```
@Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(User.class);

        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings","false");
        return properties;
    }
```

And it worked like charm.

Answer (score 10):

When you use

`@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`

or

`@GeneratedValue` which is short hand way of the above, Hibernate starts to decide the best 
 generation strategy for you, in this case it has selected

`GenerationType.SEQUENCE` as the strategy and that is why it is looking for

`schemaName.hibernate_sequence` which is a table, for sequence based id generation.

When you use `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` as the strategy you need to provide the `@TableGenerator` as follows.

```
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "user_table_generator")
     @TableGenerator(name = "user_table_generator",
                table = "user_keys", pkColumnName = "PK_NAME", valueColumnName = "PK_VALUE")
     @Column(name = "USER_ID")
     private long userId;
```

When you set the strategy it the to

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` .

original issue get resolved because then Hibernate stop looking for sequence table.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case someone pulls their hair out with this problem like I did today, I couldn't resolve this error until I changed

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto=create
```

to

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

Comment: This was the winner. How did you find this solution?

Answer (score 5):

in hibernate 5.x, you should add set hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings to false in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<session-factory>
    ......
    <property name="show_sql">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property>
     ......
 </session-factory>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Hibernate version prior to Hibernate5 `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` works like a charm. But post Hibernate5 the following fix is necessary.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,generator="native")
@GenericGenerator(name = "native",strategy = "native")
private Long id;
```

**DDL**

```
`id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

**REASON**

Excerpt from [hibernate-issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11014)

> Currently, if the hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings is set to false,
>   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) is mapped to native. 
>   If this property is true (which is the defult value in 5.x), the
>   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) is always mapped to
>   SequenceStyleGenerator.
>
> For this reason, on any database that does not support sequences
>   natively (e.g. MySQL) we are going to use the TABLE generator instead
>   of IDENTITY.
>
> However, TABLE generator, although more portable, uses a separate
>   transaction every time a value is being fetched from the database. In
>   fact, even if the IDENTITY disables JDBC batch updates and the TABLE
>   generator uses the pooled optimizer, the IDENTITY still scales better.

Answer (score 2):

You can also put :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

And let the DateBase manage the incrementation of the primary key:

```
AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

The above answer helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Entry into application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
```

Step 2 : Make sure the primary key column should be **auto increment** type

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES MODIFY COLUMN ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by [HHH-10876](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10876) which got fixed so make sure you update to:

- Hibernate ORM 5.2.1,
- Hibernate ORM 5.1.1,
- Hibernate ORM 5.0.11

Comment: I am using Spring-data-jpa which internally is using `Hibernate 5.2.17.Final` as an implementation. I am still getting this issue when `GenerationType` is `AUTO`.

Answer (score 0):

I added Hibernate sequence in postgres.
Run this query in PostGres Editor:

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 2
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE hibernate_sequence
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I will find out the pros/cons of using the query but for someone who need help can use this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, replacing all annotations `GenerationType.AUTO` by `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE `hibernate_sequence` (
`next_val` bigint DEFAULT NULL
) ;

insert into `hibernate_sequence` values (1);

Answer (score -1):

Run this query

```sql
create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
```

Comment: Request you to share the details how it solves the problem and your answer is better than the other answers...