# Avoid duplicate primary keys after database intialization in spring-boot 2

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

The default `@GeneratedValue` strategy used to work in a spring boot 1.5 web app, without duplicate id conflicts of any type

... using a simple entity such as this one

```
// in my/package/Car.java
// ...
@Entity
public class Car {
    private long id;
    private String company;
    private String model;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // ... more getters and setters
}
```

... and initializing the DB at start-up with

```
# in src/main/resources/import.sql
insert into car values (1, 'Tesla', 'Roadster');
```

... and later inserting another car with

```
Car c = new Car();
c.setCompany("Ford");
c.setModel("Pinto");
entityManager.persist(c);
entityManager.flush();

// expect no issue inserting, and a valid ID
log.info("Assigned ID is " + c.getId());
```

... used to result in a new `Car` with id `2`. I do not really care about the generated ID, as long as there is no conflict. However, this same code now throws the following exception:

`org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10095 table: CAR`
(the DB is HSQL, and I would much rather not have to replace it)

... because the [default sequence generation in hibernate 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49241216/has-spring-boot-changed-the-way-auto-increment-of-ids-works-through-generatedva) now does not take existing inserts into account.

What are my possible work-arounds to still allow the database to be initialized via `import.sql`? I know I can

- use very large ids at initialization time (but this is just kicking the can down the road, and not a real solution: eventually the sequence will catch up and break things)
- write my own sequence generator (but there has to be a much easier way of initializing a DB!)
- use the old sequence generation (but again, why did they change it if there was no advantage to doing so? hibernate developers surely had some better way of initializing things in mind!).
- somehow specify a starting value for new IDs (how do I do this in a fail-safe way? is there a property that can go into my `application.properties` to keep this centralized?)

I want to use this in the context of a spring-boot web app, and to keep it as simple and close to best practices as possible. Suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if I got your question correctly, but I have had a similar problem and the error was that I was inserting an element via a SQl statement. In this statement the ID is set to an fixed value, but your GeneratedValue is managed by Spring as far as i know and it was not able to recognize the manuel setted ID. Therefore when you insert an element using the Spring context the GeneratedValue sequence will start at 1 and throws an error, since the ID is already existing.

Comment: @MatthiasLauber yes, that is the problem. However, I need to be able to insert with SQL statements, because otherwise I cannot include relationships (which require an ID to match a foreign key value). How would you initialize a DB with IDs otherwise? An alternative way to initialize the ID would be a valid answer.

Comment: Do you use Flyway? There you write a SQL schema for your tables. You can define a sequence and tell your tables to use the nex value of the sequence for the ID generation and insert the sequence in your Spring entities

Comment: @MatthiasLauber I am not using Flyway, and would like to minimize dependencies. However, this does seem a workable solution: thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From version 5 SEQUENCE is used instead of IDENTITY for id generation. [Migration from Hibernate 4 to 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815625/migration-from-hibernate-4-to-5)

**What happened?**

You inserted record with ID 1 using script. Sequence remains at 1. It wants to insert 1 what is causing unique PK violation.

**Solution**

Don't use generation type auto. Use IDENTITY. Then inserting records by script, IDENTITY will be automatically increased. Also you don't need to insert ID value:

```
 DECLARE temp_id INTEGER;
 INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (DEFAULT, firstname, lastname, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
 SET temp_id = IDENTITY();
 INSERT INTO ADDRESSES VALUES (DEFAULT, temp_id, address);
```

Comment: Yes, I had already tested that this duplicate primary key was the problem (if IDs start in, say, 10 within the `insert.sql`, no problem is found; this is point #1 of my list of work-arounds, which obviously will fail given enough time). Using IDENTITY seems possible, however I do not understand why I do not need to insert IDs: how else can I add relationships via `import.sql`? Is there another way to initialize the DB without IDs but with one-to-many and many-to-many relationships?

Comment: the last inserted value into an identity column for a connection is available using the function IDENTITY()

Comment: The link appears to be down; I have found this: [hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html); however, I still do not know how to use this within an `import.sql` file to, say, indicate that `Car` 1 is driven by `Person` 2, assuming a `Person_Car` relationship that takes a `car_id` and a `person_id`