# hibernate_sequence doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to map a class with Hibernate annotations but it tells me that hibernate_sequence doesn't exist.

I use mysql.

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column()
    private int id;
```

this is ho I've declared the auto_increment field. What I'm missing?

Comment: I think you are asking the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968527/hibernate-sequence-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 1):

change the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` to

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

try it, It worked for me and Once the table is create, change the `GenerationType` back to IDENTITY, TABLE, or other generationTypes.

Answer (score 0):

In your persistence.xml, try adding this

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

This might possibly work.

Comment: It's not the solution and could be dangerous on production environment, because the hibernate will be able to change the database structure.

Answer (score 0):

You may manually create the sequence in db

```
create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
```

But again not all db support sequence

For example if you are working with Mysql then above query will fail.
In mysql you need to use **AUTO_INCREMENT** with primary key as in below query

```
CREATE TABLE `mysql_table` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```