# ERROR: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I am developing a very basic hibernate application and am stuck with the error:

```
ERROR: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist.
```

Attached are the related files. I see this question already been asked in stack overflow but none of them could solve the issue. I have created the sequence `school_seq` already in Oracle DB.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="hibEx">
<class name="School" table="school">
<id name="id" column="ID" type="int">
<generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">SCHOOL_SEQ</param>
    </generator>
 </id>
<property name="name" column="NAME"></property>
<property name="subject" column="SUBJECT"></property>
<property name="marks" column="MARKS"></property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

POJO CLASS

```
package hibEx;

public class School {

    private String name;
    private String subject;
    private int marks;
    private int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }
    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

First i have created sequence like the below:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE school_seq
 START WITH     411
 INCREMENT BY   1;
```

As i am facing this issue,i have tried multiple practices based on the comments in the group 
and later altered the table like the below:

```
alter sequence school_seq
MINVALUE 411
MAXVALUE 1000
NOCYCLE
CACHE 20
NOORDER
```

Comment: Show the _exact_ `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement you ran.

Comment: First i have created sequence like the below:

    CREATE SEQUENCE school_seq
 START WITH     411
 INCREMENT BY   1;


As i am facing this issue,i have tried multiple practices based on the comments in the group 
and later altered the table like the below:

alter sequence school_seq
MINVALUE 411
MAXVALUE 1000
NOCYCLE
CACHE 20
NOORDER

Answer (score 4):

thanks for your support in clearing this problem..On further research i found a comment from Li Ying in the link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968527/hibernate-sequence-doesnt-exist) .
It says In Hibernate 5, the param name for the sequence has been changed to `<param name="sequence_name">xxxxxx_seq</param>` from `<param name="sequence">xxxxxx_seq</param>`

Comment: Thanks Pavan. This worked for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sequence was created in the same schema as the table. Connect with the owner of the `SCHOOL` table and query these data dictionary views to make sure that the same user owns the table and the sequence.

```
SELECT
    s.sequence_name,
    s.sequence_owner
FROM
    all_sequences s
WHERE
    s.sequence_name = 'SCHOOL_SEQ';
```

and

```
SELECT
    t.table_name,
    t.owner
FROM
    all_tables t
WHERE
    t.table_name = 'SCHOOL';
```

Comment: Hi Julius Zaldokas, I have queried the above and for both table and sequence,the owner is SYSTEM