# Hibernate & MariaDB auto_increment is not setting FK properly with cascade

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

I'm trying to do an insert of a parent object (BulkSmsDataset) and its children (BulkSmsRecipient) at once. I use Hibernate 5 and MariaDB 10.1. I should be able to create a BulkSmsDataset and fill the `List<BulkSmsRecipientEntity> bulkSmsRecipientEntityList` with new objects then persist the whole thing at once right? But when I try to do that, Hibernate doesn't properly set the FK `dataset_id` on the `BulkSmsDatasetEntity` objects.

I get the following exception:

```java
Hibernate: insert into bulk_sms_dataset (job_id, name, template) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into bulk_sms_recipient (dataset_id, error_description, processed_on, processing_id, target) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

..... 

ERRORS:

SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000

(conn=330108) Column 'dataset_id' cannot be null

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'dataset_id' cannot be null
Query is: insert into bulk_sms_recipient (dataset_id, error_description, processed_on, processing_id, target) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), parameters [<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,'+41788718818']
```

Any idea why this happens? Why is it not setting the dataset_id correctly? Id should first insert the bulk_sms_dataset and then use the ID generated by auto_increment (MariaDB) to set the FKof the bulk_sms_recipient...

I put the code for the entities below.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "bulk_sms_dataset")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "job")
public class BulkSmsDatasetEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "template")
    private String template;

    @JoinColumn(name = "job_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private BulkSmsJobEntity job;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bulkSmsDatasetEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<BulkSmsRecipientEntity> bulkSmsRecipientEntityList;

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "bulk_sms_recipient")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "bulkSmsDatasetEntity")
public class BulkSmsRecipientEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "target")
    private String to;

    @Column(name = "error_description")
    private String error;

    @Column(name = "processing_id")
    private String processingId;

    @Column(name = "processed_on", columnDefinition = "timestamp")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.ZonedDateTimeType")
    private ZonedDateTime processedOn;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dataset_id", nullable = false)
    private BulkSmsDatasetEntity bulkSmsDatasetEntity;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipient_id")
    private List<BulkSmsPlaceholderEntity> bulkSmsPlaceholderList;

}
```

Comment: Can you try changing the GenerationType to AUTO instead of IDENTITY? I remember that I always used that type in MySQL, I used IDENTITY only on SQL Server

Comment: @vc73 I tried it and now Hibernate seems to be trying to use TABLE generation mode. I get this exception: `Table 'myschema.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist`

Comment: You probably have to set `<prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>` in your hibernate config file(SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968527/hibernate-sequence-doesnt-exist)

Comment: In case you are using JPA, set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false` instead

Comment: OK, after setting that now AUTO gives the same exception as IDENTITY: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'dataset_id' cannot be null`

Comment: Weird, are you sure the autoincrement in the table is properly set?

Comment: @vc73 Yeah it is... If I save just the `BulkSmsDatasetEntity` without the recipients it works fine and an ID is generated automatically. It's just when I try to save both it doesnt set the FK properly. Weird... thanks a lot for you trying to help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue.

I had to add `@JoinColumn(name = "dataset_id")` to `private List<BulkSmsRecipientEntity> bulkSmsRecipientEntityList;`.