# Hibernate sequence gets multiplied by 50 for `@Id` generation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
private static final String SEQUENCE = "my_seq";    

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = SEQUENCE, sequenceName = SEQUENCE)
private Long titId;
```

This creates the following schema:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1000
  CACHE 1;
```

Observation:
When I set `current value` of the sequence to 1, then the first `@Id` autogenerated is `50`. When I set the value to `1000`, the first id is `50000`.

So, somehow the current valuze of the sequence always gets *multiplied* by `50`. Why? How can I prevent this and just use the nexval from the sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior comes from `@SequenceGenerator` which has a default value of 50 for its parameter `allocationSize`. You can change it if you want :

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = SEQUENCE, sequenceName = SEQUENCE, allocationSize = 42)
private Long titId;
```

This is intended for performance reasons. It allows Hibernate to book a block of ids and prevents from asking the database each time you need a new id.

Comment: But then hibernate should use a value provided by DB, like if hibernate booked values 1-50 then it should use one of these. But why does it multiply by 50?

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this issue in Hibernate 5:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = SEQUENCE, sequenceName = SEQUENCE)
private Long titId;
```

Got a warning like this below:

> Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator]
>   sequence-based id generator; use
>   org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See
>   Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.

Then changed my code to `SequenceStyleGenerator`:

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="cmrSeq", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "SEQUENCE")}
    )
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_name")
private Long titId;
```

This solved my two issues:

1) The deprecated warning is fixed
2) Now the id is generated as per the oracle sequence.