# Java 8 + Hibernate 5 MySQL TIMESTAMP/DATETIME to LocalDateTime Mapping

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

Decided to update to Hibernate 5 to remove the existing Date to LocalDateTime conversion. I installed hibernate-java8 artifact from Maven. Then I replaced my hibernate entity date time to

```
@Column (name = "mis_a_jour_au", nullable = false)
@Temporal (TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private LocalDateTime misAJourAu;

@Column (name = "envoi_au", nullable = false)
@Temporal (TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private LocalDateTime envoiAu;
```

This exception was thrown

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property

If I remove the @Temporal then the exception becomes

> ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDateTime

I thought Java 8 + Hibernate 5 supports LocalDateTime? Please advise.

Comment: Last time I checked, it only supports Date and Calendar. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Temporal.html

Comment: Hello, I am using Java 8 and also I read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32680455 , which says LocalDateTime is supported in the hibernate-java8 artifact. I don't quite understand how hibernate handles the types apart from converter so I need some help

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't notice that article was an old article

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have and answer for you. But it seems that JPA doesn't support LocalDateTime. Here's an (recent) article about it and how to work around it. I hope this helps http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

Comment: I am currently using this workaround but I wanted to remove it because I saw the LocalDateTime support in Hibernate 5. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the line:
    `@Temporal (TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`
in each case you define it.

Hibernate 5 reads LocalDateTime as the type and correctly inserts the data into the database as a timestamp.   There isn't much information at this time due to the fact that they released the product and documentation will follow.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Column(name = "updated", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
private LocalDateTime updated;

@Column(name = "created", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime created;
```