# JPA Spring repository dates filtering returning empty array

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Invoking a query between two dates is returning an empty array, but it shouldn't.

I am using this "easy" spring repository:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.company.app.domain.DailySales;

public interface DailySalesRepo extends CrudRepository<DailySales, Long> {

    public List<DailySales> findByDateBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end);
}
```

And I invoke that method within my service:

```
public class ImplSalesService implements SaleService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private DailySalesRepo dailySalesRepo;

    public List<DailySales> getDailySales(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
        logger.debug("getDailySales with params start/end: " + start.toString() + "/" + end.toString());
        List<DailySales> result = dailySalesRepo.findByDateBetween(start, end);
        return result;
    }   
}
```

I know hibernate is getting the rights parameters because I can see in log:

```
Hibernate: select dailysales0_.id as id1_0_, dailysales0_.amount as amount2_0_, dailysales0_.currency as currency3_0_, dailysales0_.date as date4_0_, dailysales0_.tenantId as tenantId5_0_ from agg_dailysells dailysales0_ where dailysales0_.date between ? and ?
10:16:03,674 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - 2016-02-01
10:16:03,682 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [2] as [VARBINARY] - 2016-05-12
```

And copying that trace into a SQL console returns 101 items:

```
select dailysales0_.id as id1_0_, dailysales0_.amount as amount2_0_, dailysales0_.currency as currency3_0_, dailysales0_.date as date4_0_, dailysales0_.tenantId as tenantId5_0_ from agg_dailysells dailysales0_ where dailysales0_.date between "2016-02-01" and "2016-05-12";
```

Result: 101 row(s) returned

But `List<DailySales> result` gets an empty list.

What am I doing wrong?

My entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="agg_dailysells")
public class DailySales implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private Integer tenantId;
    private LocalDate date;
    private Double amount;
    private Integer currency;

    ... getters and setters go here ...
```

Comment: Which version of hibernate and Spring Data?

Comment: I am using  org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.0.Final and org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.9.4.RELEASE

Comment: @BlackBishop if it's still relevant have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, Hibernate 4 does not support Java 8 Time API. You should either use `java.util.Date` instead of any Java 8 Time abstractions or upgrade to Hibernate 5 and also add the `hibernate-java8` module to your dependencies. For more information on Java `LocalDate` and Hibernate 4 you see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750026/java-8-localdatetime-and-hibernate-4).

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate 4 does not support Java 8 LocalDate or LocalDateTime API. The reason is Hibernate 4 and JPA 2.1 was released before Java 8.\

Luckily Jpa 2.1 supports [AttributeConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) to convert attributes of entity to database column represenatation and vice versa. You can use this interface to convert between **Date** and **LocalDate**.

You have to override two method one for entity attribute to database column and another for database column to attribute.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
    }
}
```

Use this converter in your entity column definition

```
@Entity
@Table(name="agg_dailysells")
public class DailySales implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private Integer tenantId;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateAttributeConverter.class)
    private LocalDate date;

    private Double amount;
    private Integer currency;
```

Have a look on this blog [post](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/).