# Add object to database by Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring

I want to add "Father" to my database. In my database i have fields like:
id- type int,
first_name - type varchar,
last_name - type varchar,
birth_date - type date.

I did FatherEntity with this fields. In Service i did method which create new Father and i @Autowired it to my FatherController. I used GETMapping to show form and it works but when i click button "Add" i have exception like:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'birth_date' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
```

I dont know why he didn't get birth_date from form.
In entity i have bad type of field or what ?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_father")
@Data
public class FatherEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    private LocalDateTime birthDate;
    private String secondName;
    private String pesel;
```

and this is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class AddFatherToFamily {
@Autowired
    FatherService fatherService;

    @GetMapping("addFather")
    public String addFather(){
        return "AddFather";
    }
    @PostMapping("addFather")
    public String addFather(Model model, @RequestParam("first_name") String firstName,
                                  @RequestParam("birth_date") String birthDate,
                                  @RequestParam("second_name") String secondName,
                                  @RequestParam("pesel") String pesel,
                                    @ModelAttribute FatherForm fatherForm){

        fatherService.addFatherToDB(fatherForm);
        return "AddChild";
    }
}
```

and Service:

```
@Service
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "session")
public class FatherService {
    @Autowired
    FatherRespository fatherRespository;

    public void addFatherToDB(FatherForm fatherForm){
        FatherEntity newFather = new FatherEntity();
        newFather.setFirstName(fatherForm.getFirstName());
        newFather.setSecondName(fatherForm.getSecondName());
        newFather.setBirthDate(fatherForm.getBirthDate());
        fatherRespository.save(newFather);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if birth date is not null when it arrives in the controller?

Comment: i put something like this :     @Column(name = "birth_date" ,nullable=false)
in my entity but it didnt work

Comment: Which ORM framework are you using, i.e., hibernate? The reason I ask because hibernate doesn't support `LocalDateTime` and you need to implement a data type for this to work.

Comment: Yes i am using hibernate . So i try to change LocalDataTime to Data . Or .. Can i convert it to String ?

Comment: The same problem. Maybe i have bad name of field in teamplate ? Idk..

Comment: You just presented a good test case. try and convert the data to a string and verify the exception is not causing any issue. Then, if that is the case, create a data type for Hibernate to deal with the type as mentioned in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750026/java-8-localdatetime-and-hibernate-4

Comment: i get this now: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.hibernate.samples.type.LocalDateTimeUserType]

Comment: Maybe i should give you my git .. maybe i have exception somewhere else..

Comment: This is my app. can u check it ? I know i have all in models, this is my mistake and i must to repair it. https://github.com/kubcio1906/FatherAndChild

Comment: if you  have `@ModelAttribute` annotation why do you duplicate the data with `@RequestParam`

Comment: My bad. I fixed it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate throws an exception because you're passing `null` as a value for one of the mandatory columns/fields.

In turn it became `null` because `spring` wasn't able to find a correct setter in model for your attribute name. 
You see: `birth_date` and `birthDate` are two different things for spring mvc.

You can fix this in two ways:

1. Provide additional setters for your model

   ```
   class FatherForm {
       public void setBirth_date(String birthDate) { setBirthDate(birthDate);}
       public void setSecond_Name(String secondName) {setSecondName(secondName);}
       //...
   }
   ```
2. construct `fatherForm` manually from `@RequestParam`'s:

   ```
   public String addFather(@RequestParam("first_name") String firstName,
                               @RequestParam("birth_date") String birthDate,
                               @RequestParam("second_name") String secondName,
                               @RequestParam("pesel") String pesel) {
           final FatherForm fatherForm = new FatherForm();
           fatherForm.setFirstName(firstName);
           fatherForm.setSecondName(secondName);
           fatherForm.setBirthDate(birthDate);
           fatherForm.setPesel(pesel);
           //...
           return "AddChild";
   }
   ```

Comment: It works :) but .. when i click button "Add" it going to another template as it should be but when I go to my database i see empty table... ehh :D

Comment: @JakubMadej try to mark you `addFatherToDB` method with `@Transactional` annotation or maybe even entire class `FatherService`. I guess it would help

Comment: I try to learn how to use Spring and i think i must go to my teacher tomorrow, maybe he will help me with this .. i must have a little braek... :)