# what is better method before() or isBefore() while comparison of Date

Tags: java, date, java-8

i am comparing two dates by both way(old and new)

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     long  startTime1= Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     Date date1 = sdf.parse("2009-12-31");
     Date date2 = sdf.parse("2010-01-31");
     if(date1.before(date2)){
         System.out.println("date1 is before d2");
     }
     long  endTime1= Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
     long totalTime1 =endTime1-startTime1;
     System.out.println(totalTime1);

     long  startTime2= Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
     DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
     LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse("2009-12-31",formatter);
     LocalDate localDate2 = LocalDate.parse("2010-01-31",formatter);
     if(localDate1.isBefore(localDate2)){
         System.out.println("date1 is before d2");
     }
     long  endTime2= Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
     long totalTime2 =endTime2-startTime2;
     System.out.println(totalTime2);


}
```

**output:**

```
date1 is before d2
17//for using before
date1 is before d2
68//for using isBefore
```

so what is the best method for compairing because **isBefore** taking more time then **before** method but **isBefore** came in **java 8** can anyone tell when we use isBefore?

I have also checked this but i want to know in case of performance

[Should I use java.util.Date or switch to java.time.LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730136/should-i-use-java-util-date-or-switch-to-java-time-localdate)

Comment: This is definitely not best way of doing performance measuring...

Comment: so when we use isBefore() ? @Andremoniy

Comment: you use `isBefore()` when you use `java.time.LocalDate` and when you use `java.util.Date` you use `before()`

Comment: If your concern is performance, and you want to measure performance for micro calls, see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java . But I doubt date comparison performance would matter seriously in any real-life application. Date parsing is seriously fast too.

Answer (score 4):

Use the new one. `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` and `LocalDateTime` all are immutable and thread-safe. They're safer to use.

Comment: thanks @Eric for suggestion means you are saying before LocalDate  date comparision is not safe

Comment: @jitendravarshney what is meant here is that the new API (`java.time`) is much, much better than what existed before (`java.util.Date`). If you use Java 8, use `java.time` and not `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar` anymore.

Comment: ok @OlivierGrégoire Java8 DateTimeFormatter has great features as comparision to old Date

Answer (score 0):

ChronoUnit is far more efficient when comparing dates.
Here is the example which you can use:

```
    LocalDateTime timeNow = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime timeAfterSometime = timeNow.plusHours(4).plusMinutes(11);

    System.out.println("timeNow = "+timeNow);
    System.out.println("timeAfterSometime = "+timeAfterSometime);

    long minutesDiff = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(timeNow, timeAfterSometime); // 251
    long hoursDiff = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(timeNow, timeAfterSometime); // 4

    System.out.println("minutesDiff = "+minutesDiff);
    System.out.println("hoursDiff = "+hoursDiff);
```

And the output will be as follows:

> timeNow = 2017-02-13T16:05:00.617
>   timeAfterSometime = 2017-02-13T20:16:00.617
>   minutesDiff = 251
>   hoursDiff = 4

Comment: sorry but my senerio is different thanks for effort