# Room LocalDateTime TypeConverter

Tags: java, android, android-room

I need to be able to Store and Retrieve LocalDateTime properties on my sqlite database using Rooms TypeConverters.

After some researching I implemented the below converter. However, this converter appears to only store the default date time (1970-01-01). So isn't converting correctly Does anyone have a working LocalDateTime Converter? or have any improvements for this one?

```
public class LocalDateTimeConverter {
@TypeConverter
public static LocalDateTime toDate(Long timestamp) {
    LocalDateTime ldt;
    if (timestamp == null){
        return null;
    }else{
        ldt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    }
    return ldt;
}

@TypeConverter
public static Long toTimestamp(LocalDateTime date) {
    if (date == null){
        return  null;
    }else {
        return date.getLong(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY);
    }
}}
```

Comment: **`LocalDateTime` is the *wrong* class** for this purpose. Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC means this class cannot represent a moment. When tracking moments (such as a count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z), use the `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` classes. These three classes *do* represent a moment, while `LocalDateTime` does *not*.  `Instant.ofEpochMilli( milliseconds )`

Comment: @BasilBourque What would you recommend as the go to DateTime (would be in c#) parameter type ?

Comment: As I showed in the code at the end of my comment, `Instant` is the basic building-block class of *java.time*. An `Instant` is always in UTC, by definition. For other offsets, use `OffsetDateTime`. For full time zones rather than a mere offset, use `ZonedDateTime`. For date-only, `LocalDate`. This has been discussed many many times already on Stack Overflow, so search for more info. You could start with [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912754/642706) yesterday. Then search Stack Overflow using the `site:stackoverflow.com` trick in DuckDuckGo/Google/Bing for the class names.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have implemented a `LocalDateTimeConverter` in my library, Suitcase, [here](https://github.com/jguerinet/Suitcase/blob/master/room/src/main/java/converter/LocalDateTimeConverter.kt). Keep in mind that this extends my `BaseConverter` class [here](https://github.com/jguerinet/Suitcase/blob/master/room/src/main/java/converter/LocalDateTimeConverter.kt). Note: This is all in Kotlin.

If you want to implement yourself, I would recommend storing is as a String as opposed to a timestamp. If you check out the links above, you will see that I first convert the date to a String using `toString()`, and then back to a `LocalDateTime` using the `parse()` function.

Here it is in Java:

```
public class LocalDateTimeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static LocalDateTime toDate(String dateString) {
        if (dateString == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(dateString); 
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String toDateString(LocalDateTime date) {
        if (date == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return date.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

The reason the code you are using above isn't working is because in your `toTimestamp()` function you are simply asking for the hour of day as a `Long`. So given a `LocalDateTime` that is January 1, 2019, 12:00 PM, you are storing `12`. So in `toDate`, you are asking to convert the timestamp `12` to a `LocalDateTime`, which would be 12 milliseconds after midnight on January 1, 1970.

You can choose to continue using timestamps to store your date by simply changing that line in `toTimestamp()` to `date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()`. This will give you the actual timestamp for the `LocalDateTime` in the current time zone. Be aware of timezones here: as you are using the system's default timezone to save/load to/from the database, you may get a wrong value should the system changes timezones. If I use your app in New York, and then reopen the app in San Francisco all of the times will be off by 3 hours. It would be better to use a set timezone to save/load, and then convert that to the device's current timezone.

Comment: clean and simple: My original code was over complicating the task.

Comment: LocalDateTime.parse(dateString) is only available in api 26. Any backwards compatible alternatives? I have minSdk 24

Comment: I typically use [AndroidThreeTen](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) which allows you to use these classes in a backwards compatible matter. However it seems like Google is planning to add this backwards compatibility right within Android Studio 4.0, as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#j8-desugar).

Comment: @Gober, try using library desugaring -  a new feature (speaking as of today) by android. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring