# (JAVA) Need to convert DATE to prepared statement for SQL

Tags: java, sql, date, netbeans

I have been looking and trying solutions provided on the web (and SO) for the last hour on how to use the `Date` type in Java but I can't seem to get it working. I am using NetBeans 11.2 and I am **not** used to Java and it is giving me a hard time (no pun intended). It seems that `LocalDateTime`, `Date` and `Time` are deprecated and that I should be using `java.time`.

To be honest, I don't know what to do anymore. I am trying to build a query with inputs value to save in `mySQL` database.

The source of the Date is from `<input type="date">`

**SignIn.java (servlet)** :

```java
String birthDate = request.getParameter("data_birthdate");
        
UserDto userDto = null;
UserDao userDao = new UserDao(); 
        
try 
{ 
// Tried this 
    userDto = userDao.CreateUser(LocalDateTime.parse(birthDate));
// Tried that
    userDto = userDao.CreateUser(Date.parse(birthDate));
// Tried this 
    userDto = userDao.CreateUser(Time.parse(birthDate));
}
```

**userDao.java (Dao)** :

```java
public void CreateUser(Date dateBirth) throws SQLException {
try {
        connect = db.getConnect();
        ps = connect.prepareStatement(SQL_CreateUser);
        ps.setDate(1, dateBirth);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: `PreparedStatement.setDate()` expects `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`. The former is the subclass of the latter, so passing in a `java.util.Date` wouldn't work.

Comment: Re _"It seems that LocalDateTime, Date and Time are depreciated..."_, `LocalDateTime` isn't deprecated, and there's nothing wrong with using it, but steer clear of `Date` and `Time` if possible. At the risk of confusing you further, the SO question [Should I use java.util.Date or switch to java.time.LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730136/should-i-use-java-util-date-or-switch-to-java-time-localdate) has some good answers which provide a lot of detail on this issue. Also see [Migrating to the New Java 8 Date Time API](https://www.baeldung.com/migrating-to-java-8-date-time-api).

Comment: Related: [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `LocalDateTime` along with `PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()`.  Here is roughly how you would do that:

```
String birthDate = request.getParameter("data_birthdate");
// assuming your text birthdates look like 1980-12-30 00:30:05
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(birthDate, formatter);

try {
    connect = db.getConnect();
    ps = connect.prepareStatement(SQL_CreateUser);
    ps.setTimestamp(3, Timestamp.valueOf(dt));
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Note carefully the format mask being used in the call to `DateTimeFormatter#ofPattern`.  You need to replace that with whatever mask actually fits your string dates.

Comment: (1) If the datatype in SQL is `timestamp with time zone` (recommended), use `offsetDateTime` and/or `Instant` in Java. (2) Even if not, avoid `Timestamp` and use `ps.setObject(3, dt);`.