# How do I use dates from a LinkedHashMap for the x-axis on a Highcharts line graph (using Thymeleaf)?

Tags: java, spring, date, highcharts, thymeleaf

I am new to using Highcharts, so this may be a trivial issue. However, I have not had much success through my own googling about this.

I am trying to get a line graph to display strength progress over time, but every time I plug in the keySet() (of type java.util.Date) to be what is on the X-axis, the graph disappears from the web page.

I want the record of an event being done and the date it was done on to be a point on the graph (i.e. the (x,y) would be (action, date)).

**Java stuff:**

```
List<StrengthProgressPoint> records = getAllStrengthLogsForExercise(session, exerciseName);
Map<Date, Double> strengthGraph = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(StrengthProgressPoint p : records) { 
    strengthGraph.put(p.getDate(), p.getWeight()); 
}
```

**Highcharts stuff:**

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('#progressGraphContainer').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Weight Lifted'
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: [[${strengthGraph.keySet()}]],
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                label: {
                    connectorAllowed: false,
                    connectNulls: true
                },
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Weight',
            data: [[${strengthGraph.values()}]]
        }],

        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
});
});
</script>
```

I did get a graph to display on my web page a few times, but never what I wanted. I have seemingly narrowed it down to the 'categories: [[${strengthGraph.keySet()}]]' being the culprit of causing the graph to just not show up on the web page. I just want the dates in the HashMap to display on the x-axis (and correspond to the appropriate values of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using Thymeleaf with JavaScript, you need to indicate this in your `<script>` tag:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
```

Without this, the rendering from your Java objects to the equivalent JavaScript objects will not take place.

I assume you have already included the Thymeleaf namespace in the page's `<html>` tag:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Dates will be displayed on the x-axis - but the format may be a bit cumbersome - for example:

```
2021-03-15T00:00:00.000-04:00
```

So, you can add a label formatter. There are many ways to format a date, and I expect HighCharts has built-in ways to do this, but I am not familiar with them - so here is a plain JavaScript way:

```js
xAxis: {
    categories: [[${strengthGraph.keySet()}]],
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            var d = Date.parse(this.value);
            const ye = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {year: 'numeric'}).format(d);
            const mo = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {month: 'short'}).format(d);
            const da = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {day: '2-digit'}).format(d);
            return `${da}-${mo}-${ye}`;
        }
    }

},
...
```

Now the axis will use labels such as this:

```
15-Mar-2021
```

I took this formatter code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date), where there are other approaches also.

---

Worth mentioning: When you place Thymeleaf expressions in JavaScript, you can suppress JavaScript syntax errors by placing the Thymeleaf expression inside comments - and by also providing a default value in its place:

```
categories: /*[[${strengthGraph.keySet()}]]*/ []
```

In this case the `[]` is the default value. When Thymeleaf renders the expression, it will remove the `/*` and `*/` comment delimiters, and also remove the default expression.

Comment: I forgot to add a warning about not using the troublesome `java.util.Date` and moving to the modern `java.time` classes instead, wherever possible. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730136/should-i-use-java-util-date-or-switch-to-java-time-localdate) for some details.