# Parsing ISO_INSTANT and similar Date Time Strings

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I created this *wonderful static method* yesterday, and it worked just fine - *yesterday*

However, today it gives me this error. I guess it is from too many 0s before the Z.

Can anyone recommend how to parse in a concise way (Java 8) this type of `String` format date - keeping in mind that it worked yesterday too, so `ISO_INSTANT` is also a valid format for the `String`?

```
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {NanoOfSecond=0, InstantSeconds=1443451604, MilliOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
at java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:368)
at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:456)
... 9 more
```

throwing an exception on input time: "2015-09-28T14:46:44.000000Z"

```
/**
 *
 * @param time the time in RFC3339 format (e.g. "2013-07-03T14:30:38Z" )
 * @return
 */
public static LocalDateTime parseTimeINSTANT(String time) {
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
    return LocalDateTime.from(f.parse(time));
}
```

[image]

Comment: ISO_INSTANT doesn't support timezones, can be fixed with something like:
 `Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse("2017-04-20T00:00:00+04:00"))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You do not need a `DateTimeFormatter`

Parse your ISO 8601 compliant Date-Time string directly into an `Instant` using [`Instant#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-). The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse("2015-09-28T14:46:44.000000Z");
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-09-28T14:46:44Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/zZbQVA)

### What if I want LocalDateTime at UTC?

`Instant` can be converted to other `java.time` types e.g.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse("2015-09-28T14:46:44.000000Z");
        System.out.println(instant);

        LocalDateTime ldt = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-09-28T14:46:44Z
2015-09-28T14:46:44
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2fWnv1)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 24):

You are parsing a String that is consistent with an ISO instant so you need to store the result in a `Instant` instead of `LocalDateTime`:

```
public static Instant parseTimeINSTANT(String time) {
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
    return Instant.from(f.parse(time)); // could be written f.parse(time, Instant::from);
}
```

Note that this formatter handles correctly fractional seconds so you don't need to remove them. Quoting [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) Javadoc (emphasis mine):

> When parsing, time to at least the seconds field is required. **Fractional seconds from zero to nine are parsed**.

As to why it worked yesterday and not today, I have no idea...

Comment: thanks, and it's ok to do `LocalDateTime.from(instant);` ? my code is really expecting the LocalDateTime format. nanoseconds are not important

Comment: @ycomp You can convert an Instant to LocalDateTime, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19726814/1743880).

Comment: perhaps I just coded it yesterday, thought I ran it but never ran it until today - I can't see anything in my code that indicates I would have been able to run it yesterday.. so I guess it never actually worked the way I originally coded it

Answer (score 9):

Just for the sake of helping anyone seeing this question later.

You need to parse the ISO Date as `Instant`, convert it to `Instant` Object and then create a `LocalDateTime` from it providing the zone Id. I'm setting the zone Id of UTC here.

The code is as follows

```
public static LocalDateTime getISODate(String dateString) {
    DateTimeFormatter isoFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
    Instant dateInstant = Instant.from(isoFormatter.parse(dateString));
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(dateInstant, ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.UTC.getId()));

    return date;
}
```

Comment: _As a side note:_ you could use a shorter form, like:  `LocalDateTime.ofInstant(dateInstant, ZoneOffset.UTC)`, i.e. without getting `ZoneId` _explicitly_, because `ZoneOffset` (in this case it's `ZoneOffset.UTC`) extends `ZoneId`.

Comment: Aplying the shortcut informatik01 mentioned you end up in this line: `LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(dateInstant, ZoneOffset.UTC);`

Answer (score 0):

ISO_INSTANT does not have zone info. Just add that.
Or use DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME instead

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

public class TestMain {

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.withZone(ZoneId.of("Z"));

    DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime.parse("2031-12-01T10:58:30Z", formatter);
        ZonedDateTime.parse("2031-12-01T10:58:30Z", formatter2);
    }
}
```