# Convert LocalDateTime to Date

Tags: java

I have a string date, and I convert it with statement below:

```
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(rs.getString("DateIn"), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Now I want to convert `datetime` into `Date` for comparison purpose, how to convert it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Date convertedDatetime = Date.from(datetime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```