# Why are diferences between get milliseconds from LocalDateTime and Date from Calendar?

Tags: java, date, milliseconds

I'm porting my code from **`Timestamp`** to **`LocalDateTime`**, when I made a tests to get a milliseconds from **`LocalDateTime`** I saw a difference result from get it using **`Calendar`** and **`Date`**.

This is my "*test*":

```
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2016,5,19,14,8,0).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli());

System.out.println(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.of(2016,5,19,14,8,0)).getTime());

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
c.set(2016,5,19,14,8,0);

System.out.println(c.getTime().getTime());
```

I don't understand why the difference between those.

Comment: Include the results in your Question.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date.

Answer (score 2):

The result of your test is:

```
1463666880000
1463659680000
1466345280067
```

Each value is in milliseconds.

- The difference between the first two values is exactly two hours. It is because in the first line you set *UTC* timezone and in the second line you didn't set anything, so it is in local timezone (and indeed, I am currently in *UTC+2*).
- The difference in the first and the third values - apart from the millisecond part - is exaclty one month. It is because `LocalDateTime.of()` method expects the month argument represented from 1-12, but `Calendar.set()` expects month argument represented from 0-11. So in the third line you actually set *06/19/2016*.