# Calculate elapsed hours between two Java Timestamp objects

Tags: java, sql, date, time, calendar

I have two Timestamp objects, one for the current time and one for some time in the past. How can I calculate the amount of hours elapsed in between the two Timestamps?

```
java.sql.Timestamp currentTS = Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
java.sql.Timestamp lastProcessedTS = Timestmp.valueOf(<some value in past>);
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate the duration in java or in SQL? In case you want to do it in Java and you have 1.8 try this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html and that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html. Basically you can use  long ns = Duration.between(t1, t2).toNanos() to get the difference in Nanos and the datetime-instant-conversion is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date. In case you want to use sql, please specify your DB/sql dialect.

Answer (score 2):

```
long elapsedTimeMillis = lastProcessedTS.getTime() - currentTS.getTime();
long hours = (elapsedTimeMillis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Do not perform business logic on [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) objects. That class is part of the legacy date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java that have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid these classes where possible.

The java.time framework built into Java 8 and later supplants these old classes.

Much of the java.time functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 and further adapted for Android.

### `Instant`

A [`java.time.Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of nanoseconds.

If using a [JDBC 4.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index2.html) driver, you may be able to call `getObject` to retrieve a SQL column of [TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types) directly into a `Instant` object.

If not able to get an `Instant` directly, get a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) and immediately convert to java.time. New methods added to the old classes facilitate conversions.

```
Instant instant = mySqlTimestamp.toInstant();
```

### `Duration`

With a pair of `Instant` objects, define the elapsed span of time between them as a [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

Ask for the total number of hours in the entire span of time.

```
long totalHours = duration.toHours();
```

See [this similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1555262/642706) for more discussion.