# Why java.time.LocalDateTime not offering a toDate() method?

Tags: java, java-time

`joda.time.DateTime.now().toDate()`

Why doesn't `java.time.` offer such a method?
What is the best way of converting a `java.time.LocalDateTime` to `java.util.date`?

I know I could do as follows, but it doesn't feel right.

```
 java.time.LocalDateTime date;
 java.util.Date.from(date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

I'm asking because a `java.util.Date` is still used in lots of systems, like database mappings for postgres via hibernate.

Comment: A [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is not a time as such. It's a zoneless date (such as 12 May 2016 13:45), it is impossible to evaluate it as a time since the epoch without a timezone. Hence your solution, I reckon, is the neatest if you need a `Date`. A [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) is a rather different thing...

Answer (score 5):

The `java.time.*` JSR-310 packages do not contain any references to `java.util.Date` or `Calendar`. This will allow the old types to be deprecated and removed in the future.

Converting between the old and new forms is possible as seen in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date/23885950#23885950) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate/21242111#21242111). Converting "local" date-times to "instants" is always tricky, and too many helper methods can obscure the important details of the conversion.