# How convert LocalDateTime to Date in Java 8

Tags: java, date, time, java-8

I'm using timezone Brazil by default, but when caught one LocalDateTime of New York and convert to **java.tim.Instant** the **instant** is filled correctly. The problem is when I try to generate a **Date** with **Date.from (instantValue)**, instead of being generated a **date** of New York, I end up getting the current date from Brazil.

```
ZoneId nyZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZoneId brazilZone = ZoneId.of("America/Recife");

LocalDateTime ldtBrazil = LocalDateTime.now(brazilZone);
LocalDateTime ldtNY = LocalDateTime.now(nyZone);

Instant instantBrazil = ldtBrazil.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Instant instantNY = ldtNY.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

System.out.println("-------LocalDateTime-------");
System.out.println("ldtBrazil    : "+ldtBrazil);
System.out.println("ldtNY        : "+ldtNY);

System.out.println("\n-------Instant-------");
System.out.println("instantBrazil: "+instantBrazil);
System.out.println("instantNY    : "+instantNY);

long milliBrazil = instantBrazil.toEpochMilli();
long milliNY = instantNY.toEpochMilli();

System.out.println("\n----------Milli----------");
System.out.println("miliBrazil : "+milliBrazil);
System.out.println("miliNY     : "+milliNY);

Date dateBrazil = Date.from(instantBrazil);
Date dateNY = Date.from(instantNY);

System.out.println("\n---------Date From Instant---------");
System.out.println("dateBrazil: "+dateBrazil);
System.out.println("dateNY    : "+dateNY);

System.out.println("\n---------Date From Milli---------");
System.out.println("dateBrazil: "+new Date(milliBrazil));
System.out.println("dateNY    : "+new Date(milliNY));
```

**Result**

```
-------LocalDateTime-------
ldtBrazil    : 2016-09-21T22:11:52.118
ldtNY        : 2016-09-21T21:11:52.118

-------Instant-------
instantBrazil: 2016-09-21T22:11:52.118Z
instantNY    : 2016-09-21T21:11:52.118Z

----------Milli----------
miliBrazil : 1474495912118
miliNY     : 1474492312118

---------Date From Instant---------
dateBrazil: Wed Sep 21 19:11:52 BRT 2016
dateNY    : Wed Sep 21 18:11:52 BRT 2016 //this data must be related to   NY LocalDateTime, but reiceved a same date of Brazil.

---------Date From Milli---------
dateBrazil: Wed Sep 21 19:11:52 BRT 2016
dateNY    : Wed Sep 21 18:11:52 BRT 2016
```

Comment: This is because a `Date` is really just an instant of time.  It doesn't store which time zone you're in.  When  you come to print your `Date` objects, they are formatted using your current time locale, which includes your time zone.  So whenever you use `System.out.println` to show a date directly, it will always show with a time zone of BRT, or whatever your local time zone happens to be.

Comment: ok, but i call new Date(milli), and milli represents a date without timezone.

Comment: Sure, but Date.from() works the same way.  No matter how you make your `Date` object, it doesn't come with a built-in time zone.

Comment: But, in e example "new Date(milliNY))" should be ~ 2016-09-21, 21:11:52???

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: Your `instantBrazil` and `instantNY` values are _not_ the current time, because you converted them using UTC, instead of the time zones in Brazil or New York.  So you introduced an error of a few hours by doing so.

Comment: Title is dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date

Comment: This helped me straight away: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885950/845117 (which is an answer of @DawoodibnKareem referenced question.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image]

## `LocalDateTime` means no zone

You seem to misunderstand the purpose of [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

This class has no time zone and no [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). It is *not* a point on the timeline. Rather it represents a vague idea about possible moments. The name “Local…” may be counter-intuitive as it does *not* represent any particular locality, but rather *any* locality.

For example, Christmas this year is midnight at start of December 25, 2016, or `2016-12-25T00:00`. This has no meaning until you apply a time zone to get Christmas in Auckland NZ or Kolkata IN or Paris FR or Montréal CA, each being a different point on the timeline, getting later and later as you go westward.

Never use [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) because you think it will save you the hassle of zones and offsets. Just the opposite, you’ll be digging yourself into a hole with ambiguous date-time values.

## Focus on UTC

Most of your business logic, logging, data storage, and data exchange should all be in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Think of UTC as the one true time; all the other zones and offsets are masquerading as dressed-up UTC values.

In java.time, that means the `Instant` class is your go-to class, the basic building-blocks of date-time objects. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Adjust into time zones only where required to access the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) of some region. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId zNewYork = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZoneId zRecife = ZoneId.of("America/Recife");

ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = now.atZone( zNewYork );
ZonedDateTime zdtRecife = now.atZone( zRecife );
```

All three of these objects, `now`, `zdtNewYork`, and `zdtRecife`, are **all the very some moment**, the same simultaneous point on the timeline. All three share the same count-from-epoch. The only difference is the lens through which we see their wall-clock time.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Avoid using the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. So, avoid `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`. They really are that bad. Stick with java.time classes.

If you must interact with old code not yet updated for java.time types, you can convert to/from java.time types. Look for new methods added to the old classes. The [`java.util.Date.from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) method takes an `Instant`. We can extract an `Instant` from a `ZoneDateTime` (or from `OffsetDateTime`).

```
java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from( zdtNewYork.toInstant() );
```

And going the other direction.

```
Instant instant = utilDate.toInstant();
```

For more info on converting, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36639155/642706) to the Question, [Convert java.util.Date to what “java.time” type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36639154/642706)

## Avoid count-from-epoch

Avoid using the count-from-epoch numbers such as milliseconds-since-start-of-1970-in-UTC. There are various granularities used for the count (milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, whole seconds, and more). There are at least a couple dozen epochs in use by various computer systems besides 1970. The numbers have no meaning when read by humans, so bugs may go undetected.

You might find them useful when practicing. Call `getEpochSecond` and `getNano` on `Instant`, or for a truncated value call `toEpochMilli`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that you're confused about the difference between a `LocalDateTime` and an `Instant` (or a `Date`, which is essentially the same thing as an `Instant`).  These are completely different objects.

A `LocalDateTime` is a particular calendar date and a particular clock time.  You can think of it like this picture.

[image: LocalDateTime]

Or you can think of it as a year, month, day, hour, minute and second.  But it has no time zone.  It's just what the calendar says and what the clock says.

An `Instant` is a moment in time.  For example, the moment when Neil Armstrong first stepped on the moon could be represented as an `Instant`.  So could the moment JFK was shot.

Again, there's no time zone.  But it's something different from a `LocalDateTime`.  You can't write down what time an `Instant` is unless you know which time zone to write it down for.  Oh, and a `Date` is the same thing as an `Instant`.

Therefore, to convert between a `LocalDateTime` and an `Instant`, you need to reference a particular time zone.  So to express the moment Neil Armstrong stepped on the moon as a year, month, date, hour, minute and second; you need to know what time zone to use.  If you use UTC, it was 2:56am on 21 July 1969.  If you use Pacific Standard Time, it was 6:56pm on 20 July 1969.

Armed with that knowledge, let's analyse your code.  You started with a couple of `LocalDateTime` objects.

- ldtBrazil is the current time in Brazil - 22:11:52 on 21 September.
- ldtNY is the current time in New York - 21:11:52 on 21 September.

Now, you use UTC to convert these to `Instant` objects.

- instantBrazil is the moment at which it was 22:11:52 in Timbuktu (which uses UTC all year round).
- instantNY is the moment at which it was 21:11:52 in Timbuktu (an hour earlier than instantBrazil).

Then you print these out.  We need to know a timezone to be able to do this, but that's OK.  An `Instant` gets printed in UTC, no matter what.  That's what the `Z` means.

Now, you convert the `Instant` objects to a number of milliseconds.  Fine.  This is the number of milliseconds since midnight on 1 January 1970, UTC.  milliNY is obviously 3.6 million less than milliBrazil, because it corresponds to an `Instant` that's an hour earlier.

Then you convert the `Instant` objects to `Date` objects.  This doesn't really change anything, since a `Date` and an `Instant` represent the same thing, even though they get printed out differently.

You print out those converted `Date` objects.  They get printed in Brazilian time, because that's  your locale.  And it just so happens that `dateNY` is an hour earlier than `dateBrazil`; but they still both get printed in Brazilian time, which is three hours behind UTC.  So you get 19:11:52 and 18:11:52 respectively.

Lastly, you make a couple of more `Date` objects, from the numbers of milliseconds.  But these new `Date` objects are exactly equal to the `dateBrazil` and `dateNY` that you already have, since you made them from the same number of milliseconds.  And again, they get printed in Brazilian time.