# Formatting a Date with optional parts

Tags: java, date-format

I'm looking for a clean solution for formatting [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects with optional parts. My date object can be a timestamp value, a time-only value or a date-only value.

#### Expected output

I would like to display the date value like this:

If the date's [ms value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) is less than (86400*1000) then it means the value is a really a time-only value. If so display like this:

```
HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

If the date's value is exactly at midnight then it means it is a date-only value. If so display like this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

Otherwise display like this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

#### Solution constraints

Unfortunately I'm working with `Date` as the input. Can't be changed. I'm only interested in formatting/rendering, not in parsing. External libraries are a hard sell in my organization.

For the purpose of formatting it would of course be acceptable to first convert to one of new Java 8 date/time objects if that will make the solution simpler.

Platform : Java 8 SE

Comment: If you are working with Date you can not have time without date

Comment: @Jens. Is that your reason for downvote of the question? You only read first line of question? My date value comes from a library and I do not have control over it. It is what it is. By convention - in this case - values that are less than 86400*1000 are to be interpreted as a time-only value. I believe I had made that clear.

Comment: Unfortunately you forgot to ask a question in your question. You only gave us a problem description (fine) but you did not tell us where exactly you have a problem. Code is also missing.

Comment: But to suggest a beginning path: You obviously have identified some concept in your application. Make it obvious by introducing a class that represents that concept and simply takes the `Date` instance in its constructor. Then provide some useful methods in this class, especially a one for getting a formatted string. Et voila.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First step

Convert `Date` into a Java 8 equivalent structure:

```
private static TemporalAccessor toJava8Time(Date date) {
    Instant instant = date.toInstant();

    if (instant.isBefore(Instant.ofEpochSecond(86400))) {
        return instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime();
    } else if (instant.equals(instant.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS))) {
        return instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    } else {
        return instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

## Second step

Create a formatter generic enough to stringify `LocalTime`, `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` as you need:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd] [HH:mm:ss]");
```

## Usage

```
Date time = new Date(39733000L); // 1970-01-01T12:02:13
Date date = new Date(1462399200000L); // 2016-05-05T00:00:00
Date dateTime = new Date(1462442533000L); // 2016-05-05T12:02:13

Stream.of(time, date, dateTime)
        .map(d -> toJava8Time(d))
        .map(t -> formatter.format(t).trim())
        .forEach(System.out::println);

//Outputs "12:02:13", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05 12:02:13"
```

Note: I had to call `trim()` otherwise the time would begin with a space.

Comment: I'm curious about your `LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault())`, in particular the part about the zoneId. My date objects are in UTC. Date objects always are.

Comment: @peterh `java.util.Date` objects have no concept of timezone. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23885950/4370629) for a more detailled explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `java.util.Date` use the appropriate class in the `java.time` package.  This means you can explicitly have separate methods for your `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` or `LocalDateTime`, and it makes the code cleaner.

Now, if you're stuck with a `java.util.Date` and there's nothing you can do about it, you should use the `getTime()` method (which you already know about) to decide among various [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) implementations for each of your output types.

Answer (score 1):

You can try importing and using [`java.sql.Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) similar to this:

```java
import java.sql.Time;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Time ex = new Time( Date.getTime() ); //param: long
        System.out.println(ex.toString()); // prints 00:05:28
    }
}
```

EDIT: Joe C's method of going about this problem is arguably better than my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need multiple SimpleDateFormat objects for it. Your code may look like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat timeOnlySdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "HH:mm:ss.SSS");
SimpleDateFormat dateOnlySdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat dateAndTimeSdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

Date epochPlusOne = new Date( 86400 * 1000);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime( myDate);

if( myDate.before( epochPlusOne))
{
    System.out.println( timeOnlySdf.format( myDate));
}
else if( cal.get( Calendar.HOUR) == 0 && 
        cal.get( Calendar.MINUTE) == 0 && 
        cal.get( Calendar.SECOND) == 0 && 
        cal.get( Calendar.MILLISECOND) == 0)
{
    System.out.println( dateOnlySdf.format( myDate));
}
else
{
    System.out.println( dateAndTimeSdf.format( myDate));
}
```