# Breaking java date into hours

Tags: java

I receive the below startdate and enddate as input in my program.

2017-03-07 06:30:00 to 2017-03-07 11:35:00 (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss)

I want to break the dates down by hour. For the example that I gave above , I want to create a list of values similar to what is listed below.

```
2017-03-07 0630-07 
2017-03-07 07-08  
2017-03-07 08-09 
2017-03-07 09-10  
2017-03-07 10-11  
2017-03-07 11-1135
```

Can you please suggest an approach that I can explore?

Comment: Sorry Aaron , I will exit my post and will explain it clearly.

Comment: Alright I get it now ! I'll try to see what I can find.

Comment: Thanks Aaron , yes that's correct. I want to break them down by timespan. I haven't coded this yet. I wanted to check for recommended approach before implementing.

Comment: You can absolutely do this in Java, but often, when I'm doing this sort of stuff, it's a one-time job, and I use something like Python.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann , thank you. I am trying to get count of data from a specific table as part of reporting app. The query is complex is taking more than 2 minutes even after tuning as it has multiple conditions. So I am trying to cache the data by hour. If any request is coming through for data in the cache , then I would compute the count by adding up the count per hour from cache. I will query the db only for data which is not cached.

Comment: @PunterVicky Where does the Map mentioned in the title come into the picture? I suggest you either explain that more clearly, or edit your title to delete the mention if not really relevant to your core issue.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for highlighting , I edited the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use Java8, here's the approach I'd suggest :

```
// with LocalDateTime startDate and LocalDateTime endDate defined,
LocalDateTime currentRangeStart = startDate;
while (currentRangeStart.isBefore(endDate)) {
    LocalDateTime nextHour = currentRangeStart.withMinute(0).plusHours(1);
    LocalDateTime currentRangeEnd = nextHour.isBefore(endDate) ? nextHour : endDate;
    System.out.printf("%s - %s%n", currentRangeStart, currentRangeEnd);
    currentRangeStart = currentRangeEnd;
}
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/yMQYWO) you can see it in action. If you currently have `Date` objects, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date) to see how to convert from `Date` to `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Awesome Aaron! Thank you very much for your help. This looks so simple and elegant.

Comment: Yeah, the introduction of the `java.time` package in Java 8 really simplified date handling :)

Comment: Thanks again! Appreciate your time and help. just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would build a map from the start-date to a count.  Something like...

```
Map<java.util.Date,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
for (java.sql.Timestamp exactDate: dates) {
  cal.setTime(exactDate);
  cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
  java.util.Date key = new java.util.Date(cal.getTime());
  Integer count;
  if ((count = map.get(key)) == null) {
    map.put(key, Integer.valueOf(1);
  } else {
    map.put(key, Integer.valueOf(1 + count.intValue()));
  }
}
```

Then iterate over the map to pull out the values; or do a `for` loop over all possible values from the first to the last to print "zero" hours as well.

However, it's probably lest error-prone and more efficient to do the work of sorting and grouping in a database query, something like

```
SELECT trunc(log_date,'HH24'),count(*) 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY trunc(log_date,'HH24')
ORDER BY trunc(log_date,'HH24')
```

Comment: Thanks @David!! Yes , I am fetching from DB as you suggested as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42630441/642706) is good, but it ignores any seconds or fraction-of-second that may be present in the inputs. Also, I can expand a bit more, and apply time zone.

## Truncate

You can truncate the `LocalDateTime` objects eliminate any whole or fractional seconds as you increment the hours.

```
LocalDateTime ldtTruncated = ldt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ); // Lop off seconds and nanoseconds.
```

…or…

```
LocalDateTime ldtTruncated = ldt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.HOURS ); // Lop off minutes, seconds, and nanoseconds.
```

## Time zone

A crucial issue is time zone. These values lack any indicator of [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). So as correctly shown by Aaron, we should initially parse them as `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldtStart = LocalDateTime.parse ( "2017-03-07 06:30:00".replace ( " " , "T" ) );
LocalDateTime ldtStop = LocalDateTime.parse ( "2017-03-07 11:35:00".replace ( " " , "T" ) );
```

But I assume from the wording of the Question that we want to work with specific moments. A `LocalDateTime` by definition is *not* a specific moment, only a vague idea of potential moments. You must add the context of a time zone (or offset) to determine actual moment. So if you know the zone intended for these values, apply it.

The `ZonedDateTime` class makes adjustments for input values that are invalid for your particular time zone because of anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ldtStart.atZone ( z );
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = ldtStop.atZone ( z );
```

Make sure the inputs make sense.

```
// Validate the inputs.
if ( zdtStop.isBefore ( zdtStart ) ) {
    // perhaps throw exception
    System.out.println ( "ERROR - stop is befor start." );
    return;
}
```

## Date-time range as a pair of `ZonedDateTime` objects

Now we can increment hour-by-hour to generate your desired ranges. We could use the `Interval` class from the ThreeTen-Extra project (see below) which track a pair of `Instant` objects which are always in UTC. But that may not be useful for us as we really want to work with the zoned hours (or so I assume). So instead let's keep track of each date-time range as a pair of `ZonedDateTime` classes. We could create our own class for the pair, but instead we re-purpose the [AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html) class. That class tracks a pair of objects as a key and a value.

Do not let the name of that pairing class confuse you. The original intent of that class was to be used with a `Map`, but is *not* itself a map. That class is meant to refer to a key and a value *from* a `Map`, but we will use in a manner where its “key” is our starting moment and its “value” is our stopping moment.

We collect each calculated time range in a `List` of that `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry` type.

```
int initialCapacity = ( ( int ) ChronoUnit.HOURS.between ( zdtStart , zdtStop ) ) + 2; // Plus two for good measure. (not sure if needed).
List<AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<ZonedDateTime , ZonedDateTime>> ranges = new ArrayList<> ( initialCapacity );
```

Set up our loop with the starting value, and loop. On each loop we want to truncate the value to a whole hour (to lop off seconds and fractional-second). After truncation, we add an hour to get to next hour. We only need that truncation on the first loop, so you could re-write this code to be more efficient by avoiding the needless truncation on successive loops. I would not bother unless you are processing *very* large numbers of hours.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = zdtStart;
while ( zdt.isBefore ( zdtStop ) ) {
    ZonedDateTime zdt2 = zdt.truncatedTo ( ChronoUnit.HOURS ).plusHours ( 1 );  // Truncate to whole hour, and add one.
    if ( zdt2.isAfter ( zdtStop ) ) { // Oops, went too far. Clip this range to end at `zdtStop`.
        zdt2 = zdtStop;
    }
    AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<ZonedDateTime , ZonedDateTime> range = new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<> ( zdt , zdt2 );
    ranges.add ( range );
    // Prepare for next loop.
    zdt = zdt2;
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "ldtStart/ldtStop: " + ldtStart + "/" + ldtStop );
System.out.println ( "zdtStart/zdtStop: " + zdtStart + "/" + zdtStart );
System.out.println ( "ranges: " + ranges );
```

When run.

> ldtStart/ldtStop: 2017-03-07T06:30/2017-03-07T11:35
>
> zdtStart/zdtStop: 2017-03-07T06:30-05:00[America/Montreal]/2017-03-07T06:30-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> ranges: [2017-03-07T06:30-05:00[America/Montreal]=2017-03-07T07:00-05:00[America/Montreal], 2017-03-07T07:00-05:00[America/Montreal]=2017-03-07T08:00-05:00[America/Montreal], 2017-03-07T08:00-05:00[America/Montreal]=2017-03-07T09:00-05:00[America/Montreal], 2017-03-07T09:00-05:00[America/Montreal]=2017-03-07T10:00-05:00[America/Montreal], 2017-03-07T10:00-05:00[America/Montreal]=2017-03-07T11:00-05:00[America/Montreal], 2017-03-07T11:00-05:00[America/Montreal]=2017-03-07T11:35-05:00[America/Montreal]]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).