# incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Date

Tags: java, date, datetime, time

I try to store the current time and date but get the following error:

> incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Date

This is the code:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

time.setUpdateDt(dtf.format(now));

public Date getUpdateDt() {
    return time;
}

 public void setUpdateDt(Date time) {
     this.time = time;
}
```

Comment: [`DateTimeFormatter.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#format-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-) return a `String` but `setUpdateDt` accept a `Date` .. also don't mix `LocalDateTime` and `Date`, two distinct time API. Keep the most recent one, `java.time`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting between java.time.LocalDateTime and java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date)

Comment: Best if you can change the class of your `time` object to accept a `LocalDateTime` (or other type from java.time, the modern Java date and time API) so you can avoid the long outdated `Date` class completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.htm) to transform a `LocalDateTime` into a `String` with [`DateTimeFormatter.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#format-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-). Then you send that result as a parameter to `setUpdateDt`.

```
public void setUpdateDt(Date time)
```

The problem is that you send a `String` instead of a `Date`.

FYI: you are mixing the time technologies here. `Date` and `LocalDateTIme` are two distinct time API, you should not mix those. If you want your POJO to store a date, store it as `LocalDateTime`.

```
public void setUpdateDt(LocalDateTime time)
```

If you really want to get it as a `Date` from the `LocalDateTime`, check this answer: [Converting between java.time.LocalDateTime and java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885950/4391450)

Answer (score 0):

`dtf.format(now)` will return a `String`. You are getting the incompatible type error since you are trying to pass this value to the setter which accepts a `Date` object. Instead of `time.setUpdateDt(dtf.format(now));`

You could use the `java.util.Date` class to create a new `Date` as follows -

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date now = new Date();

time.setUpdateDt(dtf.format(now));

public Date getUpdateDt() {
    return time;
}

public void setUpdateDt(Date time) {
    this.time = time;
}
```

Or, if you want use the existing `LocalDateTime`, you can convert it to `Date` by -

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
Date date = Date.from(now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
time.setUpdateDt(dtf.format(date));
```

Comment: Date cannot be converted to TemporalAccessor

Answer (score 0):

dtf.format(now) returns a string. not a date object.

if you just want to convert from LocalDate to Date, you could use this method:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
Date yourDate = Date.from(datetime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

however if you still need to parse a string, you could inject a parser and assign a date object in your class.

for example:

```
public class Time {
    Date time;
     public Date getUpdateDt() {
            return time;
        }

        public void setUpdateDt(Date time) {
            this.time = time;
        }
        //this method will accept a string and inject a date format parser
        public void setUpdateDt(String timeStr,DateTimeFormatter dtf) {
            LocalDateTime datetime =LocalDateTime.parse(timeStr, dtf);

            this.time = Date.from(datetime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

        }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        Time time = new Time();
        time.setUpdateDt(dtf.format(now),dtf);
        System.out.println(time.getUpdateDt());


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
initComponents();
```

jDateChooser.setDate(new Date(fecha()));

//Formato de Fecha
public String fecha() {

```
    Date fecha=new Date();   
    SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY", new Locale("es", "EC"));
    return formatoFecha.format(fecha);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. The OP is wisely using java.time, the modern Java date and time API (`DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDateTime`). So please do not suggest using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. They are not only troublesome because of bad design, they are also long outdated.