# How can I convert a Date object to LocalDateTime in a getter method?

Tags: java, java-8, getter-setter

So I have a field of type Date, is there a way I can convert this into LocalDateTime in its getter method?
What I have so far is..

```
private Date date;

public getDate(){
return date == null ? null : LocalDateTime.of(date) }
```

But it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting between java.time.LocalDateTime and java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date)

Comment: Creating something that follows Java syntax would be a great start. You didn't define return type of the method, missing semicolon on the end...

Comment: And you probably should define what "it doesnt seem to work" means in your case other than non-compiling code.

Comment: `Date` represents an instant. To convert it to a `LocalDateTime` you need to specify a timezone.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below

```
LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime(Date date){
        return date == null ? null : date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    }
```